# how to start printing from an alphabet while i'm getting a few new lines in the start

Tags: python, string

I have to print something by taking input from a file. The first few lines are empty. Therefore the output is turning out to be empty. It's like someone has pressed enter key 10 times before writing anything.
I want to ignore those inputs and consider only those which are not empty. What should I do?

Comment: show us what you tried, so we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking if there is anything apart from a newline character (`"\n"`)is present in a line, your problem can be solved

```
fileObj=open(Filename)
for row in fileObj:
    if len(row.replace("\n",""))>0:
        print (row)
        #Do your operations
```

Comment: Hope you got your problem solved.Accept the answer if this is what you want to perform.

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit your question to add material, that would be helpful, but here’s a few pointers for now.

Assuming you’re taking the file in as a string (let’s call it `"f"`), you can loop over empty lines with a while loop:

```
charN = 0
while f[charN] == “\n”:
    f = f[1:]
```

This allows you to chop off only the initial returns while keeping any line breaks later on in the file.

Note that, depending on the system this was written in, the enters may be stored as “\r\n”, in which case you could easily alter this for loop to remove those characters too.  Good luck!